# Having issues with my <footer>

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a 3 container structure.
container 1 is of x height...container 2  fills the rest of the window...container 3 SHOULD start after container 2, but its disappeared.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xFWHk/)

HTML

```
<header>
</header>
<div id="maincontent">
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

css:

```
html,body{padding:0; margin:0;}

    header{
        background-color:red; 
        height:1.8em;
    }
    #maincontent{
        background-color:black; 
        position:absolute;
        top:1.8em;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;

    }
    footer{
        background-color:yellow;
        height:50px;
    }
```

How can i get container 3 (footer to follow container 2). 
I know its position absolute of container 2 thats causing the problem but thats the only way I can get that container to fill the screen.

I've tryed playing around with margins to no avail;

Clearer explanation of what i'm trying to achieve:

container1 + container 2 = 100% height. Then scroll to see containe 3.

I could acheive this in javascript but was hoping it was possible in css.

Answer (score 1):

Because `#maincontent` has absolute positioning, `footer` is behind it below `header`.Use `position: absolute` to put `footer` at the bottom of the page; then change `bottom: 0` to `bottom: 50px` for `#maincontent`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xFWHk/1/

Comment: The footer must be scrolled for, i don't want it starting on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change #maincontent's bottom property to the height of your footer, ie:

```
#maincontent {
   top: 1.8em;
   bottom: 50px /* Height of footer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix: http://jsfiddle.net/xFWHk/2/ ... You don't need absolute positioning in your case as "container 2" will follow "container 1" as the natural flow of the document.
CSS:

```
html, body {height:100%;padding:0; margin:0;}

    header{
        background-color:red; 
        height:1.8em;
    }
    #maincontent{
        background-color:black; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }
    footer{
        background-color:yellow;
        height:50px;
    }
```

Comment: I want the footer to follow straight after when the window is scrolled. So header+maincontainer=100% height. Then the footer follows

Comment: That's what my answer does, check http://jsfiddle.net/xFWHk/2/ unless I've misunderstood you.

Comment: Your answer the footer is at 100% + header height. But its ok i've solved it. http://jsfiddle.net/xFWHk/5/

Comment: Then all you have to do is add `margin-bottom:-1.8em;` to `footer` http://jsfiddle.net/xFWHk/6/ .. Glad you found your solution but I still think absolute positioning in this case is not needed as the natural flow of html does this for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, FINALLY!

```
footer{
        background-color:yellow;
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-50px;
    }
```

added absolute to the footer and a negative margin. Will see how this goes.